# CheckBoxList Return Checked

Tags: c#

I have CheckBoxList in a Template Field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check Box">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to check if the all checkboxes have been checked. If all check boxes haven't been checked, then you cannot advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

        bool isChecked = ((CheckBoxList)row.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")).Checked;

        if (isChecked)

            Response.Write("Its Checked");

        else

            Response.Write("Not Check");  

    }
```

The problem is that its always returning "Its Checked" even when its not. Probably because I cant use a CheckBoxList in a Template View. And Checked obviously isn't a property of the the method "CheckBoxList"

Comment: Hint: Enabled and checked are not the same thing

Comment: lol my first post and I already get a thumbs down?! Tough crowd.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CheckBoxList.SelectedItems.Count  to compare it with total items to find out if all of item are selected.

```
CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1 = ((CheckBoxList)row.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")).Enabled;    
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    if (!CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Checked)
        break;
if(i == CheckBoxList1.Items.Count)
     Response.Write("Its Checked");
else
     Response.Write("Not Check");
```

Comment: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList` does not have a property called `SelectedItems`. You are probably thinking of `System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx in asp.net Checkboxlist there is no SelectedItems property

Answer (score 0):

You should go through all items and count how many of them are checked. And than compare that value to total number of items in checkboxlist

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];  
        if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1= row.FindControl("CheckBoxList1")) as CheckBoxList;                 
           //CheckBoxList CheckBoxList1= row.Cells[cbCellIndex].FindControl("CheckBoxList1")) as CheckBoxList;                 
           int checkedCount = 0;
           foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items) {
               checkedCount += item.Selected ? 1 : 0;
            }
            if (checkedCount == CheckBoxList1.Items.Count) { 
                //all checked
            }
            else if (checkedCount == 0)
            {
               //none checked
            }
       }
  }
```

}
And Enabled simply shows if user can interact with it or not. If `Enabled == false` you will see disabled checkboxes

Comment: FAngel, This seems feasable, however because my CheckBoxList is in my GridView/TemplateField/ItemTemplate, so CheckBoxList1 isn't qualifying in the code behind.

Comment: as far as I understand, you have a problem with FindControl. See updated answer.Remember that GridView.Rows contain all rows in grid. Like footer, header and so on. So you need to check row type. Suppose DataRow is what you need. Also, I'm not sure if find control will find your checkboxlist being applied to `row`, for that you have a commented line as an alternative. Just count number of column and place it instead of cbCellIndex